# How can I decrypt MySQL passwords

Tags: mysql

The developer who created a platform my company uses is no longer working for us and I don't know how I can retrieve the passwords from a custom PHP application

When I look in the PHPmyAdmin the passwords are ecrypted (eg *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19)

How can I change or retrieve these?

Comment: Funny: the password appears to be `password` :)

Comment: *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 = password
You're welcome!

Comment: Alvaro and user1590835 - I'm surprised no one else got that ...

Comment: i am too late :))) but got very good solution for this, please check the following website for Mysql password() decryptor: https://crackstation.net/ Hope this helps someone else...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If a proper encryption method was used, it's not going to be possible to easily retrieve them.

Just reset them with new passwords.

**Edit:** The string looks like it is using [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html):

```
UPDATE user SET password = PASSWORD("newpassword");
```

Comment: There is no script to reset them unfortunatly

Comment: @Mike no need. Just run that command manually in phpMyAdmin on each user whose password you want to reset. There is no way to retrieve the original passwords without using heavy-duty cracking

Comment: MD5 was cracked long ago using the birthday attack. see for your self. https://hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx. The plain text password for the MD5 `2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19` is `password` .

Comment: @DrDeo well,. that's not pretty right. First, MySQL use its own SHA1 and unhex combined method for password hashing.
Second, MD5 has been "cracked" in a way that you can generate the same exact hash from two different inputs (because MD5's algorithm failure design). That means, an attacker could identify himself with his own generated password as the legitimate one (because he calculated the collision hash), but he can never know what the original password was. It's not reversible.
Also, what you provide is just a database of already known inputs and hashes.

Comment: PASSWORD is removed since mysql 8.0.11. is there any other way to generate?

Comment: @chancyWu - Use this: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';  
Docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 22):

> How can I decrypt MySQL passwords

You can't really because they are hashed and not encrypted.

Here's the essence of the `PASSWORD` function that current MySQL uses. You can execute it from the sql terminal:

```
mysql> SELECT SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1("password")));

+------------------------------------------+
| SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1("password")))            |
+------------------------------------------+
| 2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

> How can I change or retrieve these?

If you are having trouble logging in on a debian or ubuntu system, first try this (thanks to tohuwawohu at https://askubuntu.com/questions/120718/cant-log-to-mysql):

```
$ sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.conf | grep -i password
...
password: QWERTY12345...
```

Then, log in with the debian maintenance user:

```
$ mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
password:
```

Finally, change the user's password:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new password') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit;
```

---

> When I look in the PHPmyAdmin the passwords are encrypted

Related, if you need to dump the user database for the relevant information, try:

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host,Password FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
| User             | Host      | Password             |
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
| root             | localhost | *0123456789ABCDEF... |
| root             | 127.0.0.1 | *0123456789ABCDEF... |
| root             | ::1       | *0123456789ABCDEF... |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | *ABCDEF0123456789... |
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

And yes, those passwords are *NOT* salted. So an attacker can prebuild the tables and apply them to all MySQL installations. In addition, the adversary can learn which users have the same passwords.

Needles to say, the folks at mySQL are not following best practices. John Steven did an excellent paper on Password Storage Best Practice at OWASP's [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). In fairness to the MySQL folks, they may be doing it because of pain points in the architecture, design or implementation (I simply don't know).

---

If you use the `PASSWORD` and `UPDATE` commands and the change does not work, then see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html. Even though the page is named "resetting permissions", its really about how to change a password. (Its befuddling the MySQL password change procedure is so broken that you have to jump through the hoops, but it is what it is).

Comment: this is a needed key to enter everything lose in mysql haha

Answer (score 11):

Hashing is a one-way process but using a password-list you can regenerate the hashes and compare to the stored hash to 'crack' the password.

This site https://crackstation.net/ attempts to do this for you - run through passwords lists and tell you the cleartext password based on your hash.

Comment: That may work for simple/common password like hello, welcome etc but not all possible combinations are part of their known list.

Comment: Yes that is correct but all thing is making sure that you can not revert hashing. You can not have text back.

Comment: any idea what kind of hashing or what encryption algorithm does password() use?

Comment: i tried the above website. I am unable to decrypt the password $2y$10$os3fPHLrHAGG2GkfLE0XhOjH3fI5Fmrc8rb.W3nxIC.Oxu9pX3clq)

Comment: Hash is one way so. you can try some other website. not all will have hash. let me check this still .

Answer (score 4):

With luck, if the original developer was any good, you will not be able to get the plain text out. I say "luck" otherwise you probably have an insecure system.

For the admin passwords, as you have the code, you should be able to create hashed passwords from a known plain text such that you can take control of the application. Follow the algorithm used by the original developer.

If they were not salted and hashed, then make sure you do apply this as 'best practice'

Comment: That fell dead on its face with `2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19`. But you are right, and its probably good the guy who was responsible for it is no longer there. +1 for calling out some best practices!

Answer (score 3):

just change them to `password('yourpassword')`

Comment: they don't have to be encrypted?

Comment: +1, this is it. @Mike `PASSWORD()` encrypts them, check out the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html) to see how

Comment: Use the source Mike. How does the login part of the application check your credentials when you login?

Comment: Why is this insecure? I was not really suggesting to use the actual string "yourpassword" obviously. Is the password-hash of MySQL not save enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't decrypt MySQL passwords, because the are *hashed* by using [MD5](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Overview_of_security_issues) **hash** algorithm, which is not an **encryption** algorithm.

Comment: Which is not an **encryption** algorithm

Comment: Thanks @NinoŠkopac for correction, encryption is a more appropriate word here.

Comment: isnt md5 broken?

Answer (score -1):

Simply best way from linux server

```
sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf -e 'use mysql;UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("snippetbucket-technologies") WHERE user="root";FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'
```

This way work for any linux server, I had 100% sure on Debian and Ubuntu you win.