# mysql 5.6 update password in users db

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I Am working on installation of an application which uses MySql 5.6 Database and Tomcat as web server. After successful installation, there were two users found(admin & ascuser) by default. At first, i login(to GUI) with admin user and given (pre-defined) password. Then prompted to change admin password which went good. Later unfortunately i lost the admin password. Then i could not login to GUI. There is no option to reset admin password in GUI. There is no info provided about ascuser. I logged in to the mysql DB as root user. Passwords are hashed.
Here are few queries. Can anyone please suggest how to change/reset the password for admin user? I dont want to create any other users apart from the existing ones.

FYI:
Below are few outputs:

Mysql Query outputs
[image: 1]

Users DB
[image: 2]

I googled for password() in mysql to reset the admin password. But all in vain. Can any one Please provide some inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant crack the salted hashes .

But **yes you can reset the user Password**

check this thread [How can I decrypt MySQL passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654819/how-can-i-decrypt-mysql-passwords)