# How can I decrypt MySQL passwords since mysql 8.0.11

Tags: mysql, encryption

I'm using the mysql 8.0.15. i know there is one [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654819/how-can-i-decrypt-mysql-passwords), but in the recent version mysql 8.0.11, [PASSWORD function is removed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password). I'm trying to get back my root user password, i have got the encrypted string `caching_sha2_passIBjIZxTzot5bM9bujMxG9orfl6Ctt.w2SDLZUzAsrxD0` how can i decrpyt it? Also i try to follow solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695362/macosx-homebrew-mysql-root-password) to reset password, but without the password function, almost cannot proceed.

Comment: You can't. It's not encrypted. It's been hashed and salted - there is no way to recover the original text. Use some recovery options and boot mysqld into safe mode.

Comment: @MattClark yes, i boot the mysqld into safe mode and try to run sql like `update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('none') where user='root';' but the password is removed. not quite sure even update the password, still can be uncompressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passwords for authentication are stored in a way that's irrecoverable, it's a one-way hashing function that's applied. In this case it's SHA2.

There's no way to "unhash" this by design. The database entry contains just enough information to validate any given password, but not enough to tell you what the password is.

You can [reset the password by disabling password checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) and set a new password.