# problrm with mysql upgrade from 5 to 8

Tags: mysql

I was using the MYSQL 5 and I hashed all the passwords with password() function ,
after that I upgraded to MYSQL 8 
and all the hashed passwords with password() function are gone .
Is their any way to get the passwords again. ?

Comment: Your password hashes are not gone. The most likely case is that the function itself is gone, see [In MySQL SERVER 8.0 the PASSWORD function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52320576)

Comment: Yes you are are right , but is their any way to grep the hashes back with the right passwords

Comment: Yes, [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20834766).